# Running multi-broker config with docker and log4j to send messages: Fail-over handling isn't clear

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, log4j2

I've got the following docker (docker-compose.yml) configuration:

```
  networks: 
    brdgNet:
      name: brdgNet

  services:
    brdg-zookeeper:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.0
      container_name: brdg-zookeeper
      logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
          max-size: "2048m"
      networks: 
        - brdgNet
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

    brdg-broker-one:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0
      container_name: brdg-broker-one
      logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
          max-size: "2048m"
      networks: 
        - brdgNet
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "19092:19092"
      depends_on:
        - brdg-zookeeper
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: brdg-zookeeper:2181
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://brdg-broker-one:9092
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://brdg-broker-one:9092,CONNECTIONS_FROM_HOST://localhost:19092
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONNECTIONS_FROM_HOST:PLAINTEXT

    brdg-broker-two:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0
      container_name: brdg-broker-two
      logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
          max-size: "2048m"
      networks: 
        - brdgNet
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "19093:19093"
      depends_on:
        - brdg-zookeeper
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: brdg-zookeeper:2181
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://brdg-broker-two:9093
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://brdg-broker-two:9093,CONNECTIONS_FROM_HOST://localhost:19093
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONNECTIONS_FROM_HOST:PLAINTEXT

    kafka-ui:
      image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:master
      container_name: brdg-webui
      logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
          max-size: "2048m"
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
      networks: 
        - brdgNet
      restart: always
      depends_on: 
        - brdg-broker-one
        - brdg-zookeeper
      environment:
        - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=local
        - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=brdg-broker-one:9092
        - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER=localhost:2181
```

With the following in my log4j2.xml

```
    <Appenders>
        <Kafka name="kafka-log" 
               topic="logInfo" 
               key="UniqueKey"
               syncsend="true"
               ignoreExceptions="false">
            <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:JSONTemplate.json"/>
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers">localhost:19092</Property>
        </Kafka>
    </Appenders>
    </Loggers>
        <Logger name="logInfo" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="kafka-log"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
```

When i take out brdg-broker-one (with docker kill), I get errors trying to send from log4j and I can't view any topics on the ui anymore. Are there further configuration items I should be putting in there to get the second broker to handover during failure?

It was my initial understanding that so long as the first broker is up at start-up it would transfer the other nodes configuration through. Is that wrong?

Comment: Please show the topic definition. If you only have topic partitions hosted on one broker (and/or only one replica), then killing that broker will cause connection issues, yes.

Comment: I am using 'KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2' isn't that enough to replicate the topic?
I haven't got any additional settings for the topic - it is currently auto-created.

Comment: That's for the offsets topic, not your logInfo topic. You should disallow auto topic creation. So, based on what you said, I assume your topic will only have one replica, and only one partition which is only hosted on one broker (which you'd see if you ran `kafka-topics --describe`), as I asked

Comment: I've spent the last few days digging into this - and no understand the different configuration options with the topics and how to get them to replicate between brokers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not created `logInfo` ahead of time, the default replication factor (and partition count) for any topic will be only one.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_default.replication.factor

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_num.partitions

If the broker hosting the one replica/partition dies, then no client will be able to use it, and that data is not automatically available to other brokers to consume. Also, the producer cannot produce to a leader that doesn't exist.